How to unscrew this screw under Kitchen Faucet?

I am looking to unscrew this under the kitchen faucet.

It seems a too tight of space below but top faucet is immovable. More I pull from top, and bottom gets more firm to the frame. 

Looks to me like it unscrews from above.

Is there any labeling or etching on the faucet to say what manufacturer made the faucet? A picture of the top of the faucet may also help.

If you can't find a make or model number (which will lead to documentation) look for ways to disassemble this from above.   It may be in stages.  For example ...  a set screw to remove the faucet handle, then a nut that frees the faucet body from the mounting bracket, then a couple of screws that  hold the bracket together from above.     Note, I'm making this up ...  be open-minded about finding a path to the other end of these two screws in your photo.

Out of curiosity, does your faucet have a pullout sprayer or a separate sprayer to the side?

Show us the top of the faucet. I am betting that, with a bit of disassembly from the top, you will find bolt heads which can be turned to loosen these.

Thanks everyone for your comments. I was able to find this video and found it was a tricky puzzle to solve it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uU3xxZnFSJQ
